# How to validate an encoded url

Tags: c#, url

I have an encoded url which is invalid, I would like to validate it before decoding it using `HttpUtility.UrlDecode()`
How can I validate the encoded url below:

```
http%3A%2F%2Fwww.one-two.com&buyer=21
```

Comment: Validate against what? And why prior to decoding? What is invalid here?

Comment: If you already know it's invalid, why validate at all?

Comment: My current application gets encoded urls via web service calls, if the returned url is invalid the application throws an error and breaks. I would like to stop the app from breaking at all, the url above is a sample url returned from the web service call.

Comment: The error is the ampersand between .....com&buyer=21

Comment: How about introducing a try-catch block at the point where it crashes and simply exiting gracefully? That's what error handling is for, you know?

Answer (score 0):

You can validate url like this:

```
Uri sd;
bool b_validUrl = Uri.TryCreate(Uri.UnescapeDataString("http%3A%2F%2Fwww.one-two.com&buyer=21"), UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute, out sd);
```

If `b_validUrl=true` then url is valid, otherwise invalid.